# Send broadcast from App A and receiving it in app B

Tags: android

I am trying to send a intent String   `/Download/income_tax_return.pdf` as Broadcast from App A to App B. In the App A I have the following MainActivity.

```
package com.mysender;


import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.mysender.Data");
        intent.putExtra("path", "/Download/income_tax_return.pdf");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app","com.example.app.MainActivity"));
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}
```

After initializing the intent, I am setting the action of the intent as the following: `com.mysender.Data` and sending the intent as  broadcast to the app B `com.example.app` but when starting the App A and then App B I am not
getting the Toast message from the MyReceiver. How can I send the intent from App A to App B? I am not getting any errors.

and the follwoing AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mysender">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In the App B I am doing the following in the MainActivity:

p

```
ackage com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Receive broad Cast fromn External App
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.mysender.Data");
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

    }
    private MyReceiver myReceiver =new MyReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Data Received from External App: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml App B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Edit**

So I have registered the MyReceiver in the Manifest of the second app but I still not getting the path String:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mysender.Data" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: as per your code .after one time start app B .if your app destroy then you cant recived data from brodcast .   if its onpause mode then it will ohk

Comment: register you receiver in the manifest of B and set exported attribute to true

Comment: I don't understand why you're setting component name on the intent

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to register the intent filter in your second app, otherwise it will not listen for the intent you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

My code works I hust had to delete the following line:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app","com.example.app.MainActivity"));
```

it even works without registering the receiver in the manifest of the App B.